# Trying to display the results from a array to a textarea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I must count all the letters in one text area and output the results in a another text area.

I can do the counting part, but I can not get the results to display in another textarea. It only outputs the last item in the array.

```
  String str=enterTextArea.getText();

char[]myArry = str.toCharArray();
for(int counter =0;counter<myArry.length;counter++){
    char ch= myArry[counter];
    int count=0;
    for ( int i=0; i<myArry.length; i++){
        if (ch==myArry[i])
            count++;
    }
    boolean flag=false;
    for(int j=counter-1;j>=0;j--){
        if(ch==myArry[j])
            resultTextArea.setText(ch + ":"+"\t"+count + "\n");
        flag=true;
    }
    if(!flag){

        resultTextArea.setText(ch + ":"+"\t"+count + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: someone destroyed OP's codes by editing or the codes were really like this? this won't be compiled at all. take a look the `ch` in for(j) loop.

Comment: did another edit, hope that is what OP's original

Comment: @Kent  Looking at the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16003817/revisions) suggests the only one to change the code was you.  OP -- For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson here what I see is, Cemre edited the codes on 3rd (from history) revision. A closing `}` was removed.. What I did was just coping OP's original code to my vim, and did a `gg=G` then paste as new edit....

Answer (score 2):

You want to [use `append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29), not `setText`.

`setText` does exactly that: sets the text. Append... well, appends.

---

Unrelated, but the code is essentially unreadable as-is. Please indent appropriately.

Comment: Awesome. answer Dave. I didn't even think about appending it..
WORKED LIKE GANGBUSTERS!
THANKS a Million

Answer (score 1):

apart from the `textArea.append`, your implementation's  logic has problem too. It won't print the right result, even if you fixed the display part.

Since you said this is an assignment from your class, I just don't fix them, just point them out:

- the for loop `for(int i=0;...)` would be better changed into `for(int i=counter..) or counter+1`, depends on how would you increase the count. Otherwise some chars would be count many times. think about this string:   `ababab...[ab]x10..ab` the right result would be `a:10 and b:10`. your logic won't print that I think.
- the problem could be solved in single for loop with a hashtable-like data structure:

you loop the array from the first element, if the `char` in that hashtable, just `++` its value, otherwise put a new element into that HT,  the `char` as key, 1 as value. This HT could be declared outside the loopping. After you loop through the whole array, you just print all the elements from HT, it has the result.

hope it helps.